# Deploy to ECS using Jenkins CICD

Tags: amazon-web-services, github, jenkins-pipeline, amazon-ecs

I am trying to deploy to ECS using the below command

```
aws ecs update-service --cluster ${ECS_CLUSTER} --service ${ECS_SERVICE} --force-new-deployment --region ${AWS_REGION}
```

but the above command fails with the below error.

```
C:\ProgramData\Jenkins.jenkins\workspace\e-learning>docker tag my-nginx-image:latest 456787.dkr.ecr.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/my-nginx-image:latest [Pipeline] bat
    
C:\ProgramData\Jenkins.jenkins\workspace\e-learning>aws ecs update-service --cluster ecs_cluster --service ecs_service --force-new-deployment --region eu-west-2
    
An error occurred (ClusterNotFoundException) when calling the UpdateService operation: Cluster not found.
```

Code:

```
stage('Deploy to ECS') {
steps {

        withCredentials([[$class: 'AmazonWebServicesCredentialsBinding', accessKeyVariable: 'AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID', credentialsId: 'my-aws-credentials', secretKeyVariable: 'AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']]) {
          bat "aws ecr get-login-password --region ${AWS_REGION} | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin ${AWS_ACCOUNT_ID}.dkr.ecr.${AWS_REGION}.amazonaws.com"
         
          bat "docker pull ${AWS_ACCOUNT_ID}.dkr.ecr.${AWS_REGION}.amazonaws.com/${IMAGE_NAME}:${IMAGE_TAG}"
          bat "docker tag ${IMAGE_NAME}:${IMAGE_TAG} ${AWS_ACCOUNT_ID}.dkr.ecr.${AWS_REGION}.amazonaws.com/${IMAGE_NAME}:${IMAGE_TAG}"
          bat "aws ecs update-service --cluster ${ECS_CLUSTER} --service ${ECS_SERVICE} --force-new-deployment --region ${AWS_REGION}"
```

Can anybody help. I'm new into aws

For the aws ecs update to deply the service`

Comment: Is your cluster actually named `ecs_cluster`?

Comment: Have you tried to list the cluster using the aws commands ?